# SwiftUI Animation similar to that of the Apple Podcasts app expanding player

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So I'm trying to mimic the Apple Podcasts app expanding audio player.

[image]

So far I've added an overlay to my TabView and it works like a charm, se below:

```
TabView {
    ...
}.overlay(
    PlayerView()
)
```

Now I want to achieve the expanding view/sheet similar to the gif above for my `PlayerView()`, how would I go about doing that in SwiftUI?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you running into a problem? Stack Overflow is best for specific questions: [ask], [mre]

Comment: @jtbandes I manged to solve it so will posting the answer here shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this issue after some time researching, was a bit of hassle getting the animation working smoothly but I think I got it in the end. See code below:

**App.swift**

```
TabView {
    ...
}.overlay(
    FloatingPlayer()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
)
```

**FloatingPlayer.swift**

```
struct FloatingPlayer: View {
    @State var viewState = CGSize.zero
    @State var playerExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                if self.playerExpanded {
                    Spacer()
                }
                ZStack {
                    VisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: self.settings.playerExpanded ? .systemThickMaterialDark : .dark))
                            .frame(
                                width: geometry.size.width,
                                height: self.playerExpanded ? geometry.size.height + 10 : 60
                            )
                }
                     .offset(y: self.viewState.height)
                     .gesture(DragGesture()
                     .onChanged { value in
                         if (self.playerExpanded) {
                             self.viewState = value.translation
                             if (value.translation.height > 200) {
                                 self.playerExpanded = false
                                 self.simpleSuccess()
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     .onEnded { value in
                          self.viewState = CGSize.zero
                     })
                     .onTapGesture {
                         if !self.playerExpanded {
                             self.playerExpanded.toggle()
                         }
                     }
            }
                .animation(.interactiveSpring(response: 0.5, dampingFraction: 0.9, blendDuration: 0.3))
                .statusBar(hidden: true)
        }
    }
}
```

You would also need to play with some paddings in order for it to work perfectly.